# UIRefreshControl refresh sticks on rotation

Tags: swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a view controller with a table view and a refresh control. When I rotate screen during the refresh, refresh control sticks. I've tried to add .endRefreshing() on the viewWillTransition and tableview.refreshData() in vain. None of the solutions I could find works.

Comment: Try adding an observer to detect orientation changes and end the refresh from there. It should sort you out

Comment: I added this observer to ViewDidLoad: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil) and func deviceOrientationDidChange() {     
        refreshControl.endRefreshing() }. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue in my application and found work around to un stick refresh control.you can set the tableview contentoffset. it will reset your tableview to up.

```
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
```